# How to aggregate data within two grouping variables (group in group)?

Tags: r, aggregate, longitudinal

I want to aggregate data in long format. I have an ID variable, a year variable, and two other interesting variables. I now want to aggregate the variables within a person within a year.

This is how my original data frame looks like:

```
   ID year month      x    y
 1 A  2014     3      2    NA
 2 B  2010     2      3    NA
 3 B  2010     5     NA    21
 4 B  2011     2      2    NA
 5 B  2011     5     NA    25
 6 C  2012     5     NA    23
 7 C  2013     2      2    NA
 8 C  2013     5     NA    22
 9 C  2014     2      1    NA
10 C  2014    11     NA    30
```

This is how I would like to have it:

```
   ID year month      x1   y1
 1 A  2014     3      2    NA
 2 B  2010     2      3    21
 3 B  2010     5      3    21
 4 B  2011     2      2    25
 5 B  2011     5      2    25
 6 C  2012     5      NA   23
 7 C  2013     2      2    22
 8 C  2013     5      2    22
 9 C  2014     2      1    30
10 C  2014    11      1    30
```

Whenever a person has two measures in one year (e.g., Person B has two measures in 2010 and in 2011), I would like to aggregate the x and y values within this person and within each year. Later I would like to have a data frame that contains only one row per year but with all information on x and y.

like this:

```
   ID year month      x1   y1
 1 A  2014     3      2    NA
 2 B  2010     5      3    21
 3 B  2011     2      2    25
 6 C  2012     5      NA   23
 7 C  2013     5      2    22
 9 C  2014     2      1    30
```

Do you have any advices how to do this? Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `na.locf0` from `zoo`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID, year) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(x, y),  list(~ na.locf0(na.locf0(., fromLast = TRUE))))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   ID, year [6]
#   ID     year month     x     y
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A      2014     3     2    NA
# 2 B      2010     2     3    21
# 3 B      2010     5     3    21
# 4 B      2011     2     2    25
# 5 B      2011     5     2    25
# 6 C      2012     5    NA    23
# 7 C      2013     2     2    22
# 8 C      2013     5     2    22
# 9 C      2014     2     1    30
#10 C      2014    11     1    30
```

---

Or using `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID, year) %>%
    fill(x, y, .direction = 'up') %>%
    fill(x, y)
```

To get the final output

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID, year) %>%
  fill(x, y, .direction = 'up') %>%       
  slice(1)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID, year [6]
#  ID     year month     x     y
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 A      2014     3     2    NA
#2 B      2010     2     3    21
#3 B      2011     2     2    25
#4 C      2012     5    NA    23
#5 C      2013     2     2    22
#6 C      2014     2     1    30
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
 "C", "C"), year = c(2014L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L), month = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
 2L, 5L, 2L, 11L), x = c(2L, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA
 ), y = c(NA, NA, 21L, NA, 25L, 23L, NA, 22L, NA, 30L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to list both variables as:

aggregate(x, by= list(ID, year), FUN="yourfunctionhere")

Answer (score 0):

This would work also:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, year) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(one_of(c("x", "y"))), 
               ~ if (length(.x) == 1 && is.na(.x)) NA else sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE))
```